# Failed to sync Gradle project 'Happy Birthday'

Tags: android-studio

The error displayed when i open a new project on android studio. I have tried rebuilding the gradle, uninstalling and reinstalling android studio but still it does not work.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello saleem have you tried to build using local gradle [download](https://gradle.org/downloads/) it and try config your studio to use local gradle in settings.